# How to plot a antenna pattern in MATLAB given by a normalized field pattern?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to use MATLAB to create a polar plot of an antenna pattern given a normalized field pattern (remember 0<<180°). The antenna pattern is in this image:

[image: antenna pattern]

I was trying to create a function to plot it but when I call the function I created, I get an error. Can anyone help?

My current code I have so far is in this image:

[image: my current code]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please include the code as text, so we can try it. Also, please indicate which error you get. Also, note that the `sym` declarations are overwritten when you initiallize to `zeros` (which has type `double`). You would better initiallize to `zeros(1,100)` to avoid having the arrays grow. And you can probably get rid of the `for` loop with vectorization

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a [**vectorized**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) manner using [element-wise operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html) instead of a loop.

Note that, although the variables are defined as symbolic in your code, they are then changed to `double` when you initiallize them with `zeros`.

The mathematical function is undefined at `theta`= `pi`. Its limit is `0`, but if you compute it directly with `double` precision you get the value `-1.5`, produced by numerical inaccuracies inherent to floating-point data types. The best way to avoid this issue is to use an **odd number of samples**, so that `theta` is never too close to `pi`.

Lastly, the [`polar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html) function is **not recommended**. It's better to use [`polarplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html).

```
N = 101; % odd number of samples
theta = (0:N-1)/N*2*pi;
f = cos(1.5*pi*cos(theta))./sin(theta); % vectorized. Note element-wise division
polar(theta, f)
```

[image]